# 3DS2 successful even when entering wrong challenge code with direct integration

Tags: opayo

We have upgraded our current direct integration to support VPS Protocol 4.00 however when testing failed 3DS the response from Sagepay is still successful.

```
VPSProtocol=4.00
Status=OK
StatusDetail=0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.
VPSTxId={1BD691A9-390E-1FFD-00AC-FC361B7084CF}
SecurityKey=OX3CM8KFRZ
TxAuthNo=2361964
AVSCV2=SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY
AddressResult=NOTMATCHED
PostCodeResult=NOTMATCHED
CV2Result=MATCHED
3DSecureStatus=NOTAUTHED
DeclineCode=00
ExpiryDate=0120
BankAuthCode=999777
```

When entering a failed 3DS code, we expect to see a "Invalid" response from Sagepay but we are receiving an OK. Interestingly within MyTestSagepay, the 3DS settings reports the following: "**3D Secure is currently being set up on your account. As soon as it's available, you'll be able to switch it ON and OFF from here.**"

Is this a problem with the test account?

Comment: I would check with SagePay if 3DSecure was enabled for your account a while ago. If you just did it recently, I guess you need to wait until it's set up. Then you need to turn it on.

Comment: I'm struggling with getting CRes value, how do i get this value? I get to the page where it asks to type in "challenge" but then when it redirects to ThreeDSNotificationURL how do i get the CRes value? Any help appreciated!

Comment: @S.Simkhada The bank posts to the ThreeDSNotificationURL, Have a look at my answer on that post: 3DSv2 Sagepay Direct Integration basics. That's for asp.net c#. Might give an idea for PHP.